# How do I keep from bleeding to death after I punch this window?

Tags: cryptozookeeper

I'm playing [Cryptozookeeper](http://www.joltcountry.com/index.php/robbsherwin_videogame/cryptozookeeper).

I need to retrieve an ape, and circumstances suggest the correct course of action is to punch this window so that I can break into the facility where it's being held. As soon as I do so, my companions are aghast, and I begin bleeding profusely.

At this point, I only have a few turns to address my medical condition.

I've tried checking the room for medical supplies, but all I've found is a receipt in a filing cabinet. Before getting too much further, I bleed to death.

How do I keep this from happening? Is there a better way into the building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some industrial compound inside a box in the room that you enter. If you go to take it, it will heal your hand up.